# Selecting and Deleting From Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql

When writing a database convert script I have come across an issue of there being duplicate records, my aim is to find these and remove the duplicates. I am in no way an expert in SQL so seek abit of advice!

The best thing I have been able to come up with so far to find and delete the duplicate records (if group_name and level) are the same is this

```
DELETE FROM achievements
WHERE group_name IN (SELECT concat(group_name, level)
                     FROM achievements
                     GROUP BY group_name, level
                     HAVING count(*) >1);
```

But it gives me the following error

> [Err] 1093 - Table 'achievements' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Here is my current data; https://gist.github.com/Diddyy/13842901c830c19c21488613c9d27c92

From that data there are 3 duplicates (group_name followed by level);
ACH_CameraPhotoCount 5
ACH_FootballGoalScoredInRoom 1
ACH_FootballGoalScoredInRoom 2

I class these as duplicates as there is already an entry with the same name and level.

My end result is to remove the 3 duplicates but leave behind one of each so it still exists.

Note, duplicate group_name is allowed. Duplicate level is allowed. But what I don't want is a group_name with the same level more than once.

I can't seem to come up with a solution for this, as well as I'm not too sure concat would be the best way?

Open to any solutions, thank you!

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added information, apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to remove duplicates in MySQL is to use `join`.  The following removes *all* `group_name`s that occur more than once:

```
delete a
    from achievements a join
         (select group_name, min(level) as minlevel
          from achievements a
          group by group_name
          having count(*) > 1
         ) aa
         on a.group_name = aa.group_name;
```

The following does what is more common.  It keeps *one* "duplicate" row, say the one with the lowest level:

```
delete a
    from achievements a join
         (select group_name, min(level) as minlevel
          from achievements a
          group by group_name
          having count(*) > 1
         ) aa
         on a.group_name = aa.group_name
    where a.level > aa.level;
```

EDIT:

You can do the same thing with `group_name` and `level`:

```
delete a
    from achievements a join
         (select group_name, level, min(id) as minid
          from achievements a
          group by group_name, level
          having count(*) > 1
         ) aa
         on a.group_name = aa.group_name and a.level = aa.level
    where a.id > aa.minid;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have the end result I'm hoping for, it was my fault as I didn't explain what i wanted to achieve accurately. I'm wanting to remove duplicates where group_name + level already exsist. An example in my data would be ACH_CameraPhotoCount - 5. This is a duplicate as there is already an entry for group_name ACH_CameraPhotoCount with the level 5. See Original Post for my current data. Sorry!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and solution, it has achieved exactly what I was hoping for!